# SwiftUI Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI app, its a tab based app

```
struct Tab_View: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView{
            Main1_View().tabItem {
                Text("Blah 1")
                Image("TabBar1")
            }
        
            Main2_View().tabItem {
                Text("Blah 2")
                Image("TabBar2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each view has its own view controller

```
struct Main1_View: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: Main1_ViewModel = Main1_ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing:0){
           <<< VIEW CODE >>>
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel Example

```
class Main1_ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @ObservableObject var settings: GameSettings

    func Randomise(){
        dataSource = settings.selectedFramework;
    }
}
```

The class GameSettings is used by multiple viewmodels, is an ObservableObject, same instance of the class everywhere.

My background is C# and using CastleWindsor for dependency injection.

My Question: Is there a SwiftUI equivalent to pass around an instance of GameSettings?

Answer (score 3):

Because of your requirement to use an `ObservableObject` (`GameSettings`) inside another `ObservableObject` (the view model) *and* use dependency injection, things are going to be a little bit convoluted.

In order to get a dependency-injected `ObservableObject` to a `View`, the normal solution is to use `@EnvironmentObject`. But, then you'll have to pass the object from the view to its view model. In my example, I've done that in `onAppear`. The side effect is that the object is an optional property on the view model (you could potentially solve this by setting a dummy initial value).

Because nested `ObservableObject`s don't work out-of-the box with `@Published` types (which work with value types, not reference types), you'll want to make sure that you use `objectWillChange` to pass along any changes from `GameSettings` to the parent view model, which I've done using `Combine`.

The `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` part is there just to show that the view *does* in fact update when the value inside `GameSettings` is changed.

*(Note, I've also changed your type names to use the Swift conventions of camel case)*

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var settings = GameSettings()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Main1View().tabItem {
                Text("Blah 1")
                Image("TabBar1")
            }
        
            Main2View().tabItem {
                Text("Blah 2")
                Image("TabBar2")
            }
        }.environmentObject(settings)
    }
}

struct Main1View: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var settings: GameSettings
    @StateObject var viewModel: Main1ViewModel = Main1ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing:0){
            Text("Game settings: \(viewModel.settings?.myValue ?? "no value")")
        }.onAppear {
            viewModel.settings = settings
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                settings.myValue = "changed"
            }
        }
    }
}

class GameSettings : ObservableObject {
    @Published var myValue : String = "Test"
}

class Main1ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
    var settings: GameSettings? {
        didSet {
            print("Running init on Main1ViewModel")
            self.objectWillChange.send()
            cancellable = settings?.objectWillChange.sink(receiveValue: { _ in
                print("Sending...")
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            })
        }
    }
}

struct Main2View : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just pass GameSettings into the init of the ViewModels?

Comment: Because you don't have access to the environment at the time of `init` of the `@StateObject` property wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection, DI is the practice of providing an object with the other objects it depends on rather than creating them internally.

My Opinion
For SwiftUI you can use @EnvironmentObject. @EnvironmentObject and the View Model Factory both provide a clean solution to this.

Check this tutorial
https://mokacoding.com/blog/swiftui-dependency-injection/