# How can a nested ObservableObject reference the parent EnvironmentObject - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

## How can a nested ObservableObject reference the parent

```
Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Model found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for Model may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
```

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var subModel = SubModel()
    @Published var email: String = ""
}

class SubModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model // This EnvironmentObject doesn't work. See error.
    
    func run() {
        model.email = "new@test.com" // How can I update the email here? Throws error..
        // Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Model found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for Model may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model // This EnvironmentObject works great
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            model.subModel.run()
        }) {
            Text("Click me")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote this recently about the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69238617/560942

Comment: You have to observe the submodel individually. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68710726/swiftui-view-updating/68713038#68713038